# Sound not forwarding properly to Bluetooth speakers

Tags: sound, bluetooth, 20.04, pulseaudio

I am on `Ubuntu 20.04` and I have a Sony SRS-XB10 Bluetooth speaker. It says connected to the Laptop but while I play sounds in my system, not all of the application's sound is forwarded to the Bluetooth speaker.

For example, system alert sounds are playing on the Bluetooth speaker, whereas the VLC's sound is being played on Laptop Speaker.

I tried to tweak all possible combination of output device from sound settings but no progress.

I also tried reconnecting and restarting and it doesn't help either.

Any idea why this is happening and how it can be mitigated?

Answer (score 0):

I only know enough to be dangerous, but maybe this will give you some places to read more information. I also have 20.04 and I also have had audio issues (different than yours). I found that

> sudo alsa force-reload

gave me temporary relief, but purging and reinstalling alsa-base and pulseaudio may have made my situation worse. So if you decide to try that, be aware that the reinstall may not have all of the same packages as the legacy install (is that possible, I can't look back and verify?)